# How does vitamin A deficiency arise?

Tags: food, vitamins

How does vitamin A deficiency arise?

I am living in a "developed" country, so excuse me if I miss some facts
that are real, and threatening, in other parts of our world.

I heard about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitamin_A_deficiency ,
but looking at what foodstuff contains vitamin A or precursors,
I'm at loss how anyone can suffer from vitamin A deficiency.

Obviously, I'm lacking some information here.

One thing that looks particularly misleading is when you are
presented with vitamin A contents of foods, neglecting precursors
like carotenoids that can be easily converted to vitamin A as needed.

As a (sometimes misleading) rule of thumb, I was thinking that most
yellow or orange looking food was prone to contain vitamin A or some
of its precursors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHO report **"[Global
 prevalence of
vitamin A deficiency
in populations
 at risk
1995–2005](http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/44110/1/9789241598019_eng.pdf)"** (page 12 of 68) puts it like this:

> Where animal source or fortified foods are minimally consumed, dietary
>   adequacy must rely heavily on foods providing beta-carotene. However,
>   while nutritious in many ways, **a diet with modest amounts of
>   vegetables and fruits as the sole source of vitamin A may not deliver
>   adequate amounts**, based on an intestinal carotenoid-to-retinol
>   conversion ratio of 12:1 (2)  This ratio reflects a conversion
>   efficiency that is about half that previously thought, leading to
>   greater appreciation for why VAD may coexist in cultures that heavily
>   depend on vegetables and fruits as their sole or main dietary source
>   of vitamin A.
>
> Usually, VAD develops in an environment of ecological, social and
>   economical deprivation, in which a chronically deficient dietary
>   intake of vitamin A coexists with severe infections, such as measles,
>   and **frequent infections causing diarrhoea and respiratory diseases
>   that can lower intake through depressed appetite and absorption**, and
>   deplete body stores of vitamin A through excessive metabolism and
>   excretion (3, 4). The consequent “synergism” can result in the body’s
>   liver stores becoming depleted and peripheral tissue and serum retinol
>   concentrations decreasing to deficient levels, raising the risks of
>   xerophthalmia, further infection, other VADD and mortality.

Just as a side note: green leaves contain heaps of beta-carotenes as well!